# User relationship requests in a view block with accept and decline links

Tags: 7, actions, users

I have a node in which i want to show a user all the relationship requests the current user has received and a status link below that so that the user can accept or decline the request then and there itself without needing to go to the boring Drupal default user relationship page. I am obviously using the user relationship module for this purpose. Anyways, i set out to create a view but after tinkering enough i was unable to do so. What i was able to do was to get a list of all relation requests (also made by the logged in user) I want only the received request.  How can i do this? If it helps, here's my view [image]

Answer (score 2):

Add requestee relation. 
Add context filter by user id (set it on current user with requestee relation). Add filter criteria by relationship status.

Here you can see screenshot of view.

[image]